# Retrieve gs:// path for a storage Bucket and Object at GCS using Python api client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I'm working on a script to create google cloud functions using api, in which i need to get gs:// form of path to the storage bucket OR Object,

Here's what i have tried:

```
svc = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', http=views.getauth(), cache_discovery=False)
            svc_req = svc.objects().get(bucket=func_obj.bucket, object=func_obj.fname, projection='full')
            svc_response = svc_req.execute()
            print(' Metadata is coming below:')
            print(svc_response)
```

It returns metadata which doesn't include any link in the form of **gs://** , how can i get the path to a bucket OR Object in the form of **"gs://"**

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/storage/v1/storage.objects.get) and simulate your request you will see that this library returns you exactly the same output in python data structures. In there ID looks the most like `gs://` link:

```
"id": "test-bucket/text.txt/0000000000000000"
```

or in python it looks like:

```
u'id': u'test-bucket/text.txt/00000000000000000'
```

Simple use this to transform it into a `gs://` link:

```
import os
u'gs://' + os.path.dirname(svc_response['id'])
```

which would return:

```
 u'gs://test-bucket/text.txt'
```

If you want to use the [google-cloud-python](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.id) you will be facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, @A.Queue ! thanks for your answer, actually i'm working on cloud functions API in python in which i need to create a function by using api, I'm sending a request with the body as: `req_body = {
                        "name": func_obj.fname,
                        "entryPoint": func_obj.entryPoint,
                        "timeout": '60s',
                        "availableMemoryMb": func_obj.fmemory,
                        "sourceArchiveUrl": mediaLink,
                }` but it returns **request has error** can you help me regarding this, please!

Comment: OR take a look at this question, please!                                             https://stackoverflow.com/q/47376380/7644562