# Get Runtime Service Account running a Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to get the email of the Runtime Service Account programmatically from a Cloud Function?

[image: Runtime Service Account option]

I know I can "guess" the default App Engine account (since it is always <project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com), but this is not what I want.

I was expecting to have some [Environment Variable](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) or something with this information, but I was not able to find any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For older runtimes (Node.js 8, Python 3.7 and Go 1.11), you can use `FUNCTION_IDENTITY` environment variable, as [described here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_8_python_37_and_go_111).

Example in Python:

```python
import os
service_account_email = os.environ.get('FUNCTION_IDENTITY')
```

For newer runtimes, you need to query the [Metadata Server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata), as in this example:

```python
import requests
def query_metadata(entry):
    response = requests.get('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/' + entry, headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'})
    return response.content.decode("utf-8")

service_account_email = query_metadata('instance/service-accounts/default/email')
```

You can also write a function that supports both runtimes (older and newer) using:

```python
service_account_email = os.environ.get('FUNCTION_IDENTITY') or query_metadata('instance/service-accounts/default/email')
```

For a list of metadata endpoints that you can use to query for information, [check here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the newer runtimes, you can get the runtime service account of your Cloud Function programmatically using REST API. Here's an example based from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609309/create-a-google-function-from-a-google-cloud-function):

```
import requests
import json

def get_sa():
  FUNCTION_NAME = 'func_name'
  PROJECT_ID = 'proj_id'
  REGION = 'us-central1'

  # Get the access token from the metadata server
  metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
  token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
  token_response = requests.get(metadata_server_token_url, headers=token_request_headers)
  token_response_decoded = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")
  access_token = json.loads(token_response_decoded)['access_token']

  # Call functions.get() to retrieve Cloud Functions information
  response = requests.get('https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{}/locations/{}/functions/{}'.format(PROJECT_ID, REGION, FUNCTION_NAME),
    headers={
      'Accept': 'application/json', 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
      })   
  print(response.json()['serviceAccountEmail'])

get_sa()
```

Note that you can only get an access token from the metadata server if your app is deployed in GCP (Compute Engine, Cloud Functions, etc.). If your app is on your local machine, you need to use a service account and an auth library to generate the access token. Here's the auth library [reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/) if you're using Python.

To learn more about the given REST API method, see [`projects.locations.functions.get()`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/get).

Comment: Your solution is interesting, but forces me to hardcode function name, project, and region, which leads me to the same problem: If it was the case, it would be easier to just set a variable with the e-mail in the code.